# Regex for allowing no space and no value, A, AR, or Ar in the start

Tags: java, regex

```
^([A-Z]{0,1}|[A-Za-z]{0,2})(\s{0,5})([A-Za-z]{1,5}|[\d]{1,5})([']{0,1})(\s{1})([A-Z]{1,2})([a-z]{0,2})(\s{1,2})([A-Za-z]{1,5}|[\d]{1,5})
```

valid case

> Mz A Lt 1
>
> Mz B' Lt 4

I was trying the following regular expression where the valid inclusion would be: no value, A, AR, or Ar and no space if nothing present in first
and Apostrophe (') optional, then SPACE required based on if there is any letter present after Apostrophe.(A, AR, or Ar are examples for ref valid for All chars)

Invalid case will be like ARrd A Lt 1 or aa B Lt' 2

Rules

a)1-2 letter; second letter optional Lower Case: Min 0, Max 2

b) SPACE as a conditional requirement based on letter(s) presence before

c) 1-5 number or 1-5 letter any combination: Min 1, Max 5

d) Apostrophe (') optional

e) SPACE required
f) 1-2 letter; second letter optional Lower Case: Min 0, Max 2

g) SPACE as a conditional requirement based on letter(s) presence before

h) 1-5 number; Min 1, Max 5

but my regex allows all lower cases too which i was trying to avoid can anyone help me out

Comment: Thanks but i don't to entirely  block A or R it was just an example 
 `^([A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z])(\s{0,5})([A-Za-z]{1,5}|[\d]{1,5})([']{0,1})(\s{1})([A-Z]{1,2})([a-z]{0,2})(\s{1,2})([A-Za-z]{1,5}|[\d]{1,5})`

Comment: this is what I tried later

Comment: Sorry, it is next to impossible to help you since your rules are not clear. It is not clear why you tried the regex above. Please update the question with the "step-by-step" format explanation.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/5xIUM9/2, does it work as required? If not please add more test cases.

Comment: I updated some test cases in the link u provided, further more I tried 
`^([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z][A-Z]{2}|[A-Za-z]{0,2})(\s{0,5})([A-Za-z]{1,5}|[\d]{1,5})([']{0,1})(\s{1})([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z][A-Z]{2}|[A-Za-z]{0,2})(\s{1,2})([A-Za-z]{1,5}|[\d]{1,5})`

Comment: The regex you are using above does not fit your requirements, `([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z][A-Z]{2}|[A-Za-z]{0,2})` matches no text or 1 to 2 upper- or lowercase letters. Why are you using it if the first one should be upper- and the second can only be lowercase? Please revise your requirements. (see *`1-2 letter; second letter optional Lower Case: Min 0, Max 2`*)

Comment: Also, see https://regex101.com/r/5xIUM9/4

Comment: The new url works partially I tried `B' Lt 4` removing 4 from the example and it was going the Rules line in your new example I will try some more examples 

second letter can optionally be lower case not always

Comment: You are doing a very wrong thing: testing patterns online. Test them in the target environment. Also, why remove `4`? It is not optional acc. to your requirements (see *`1-5 number; Min 1, Max 5`*)

Comment: Yes you are right , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/vho6Tn/24
This works for all the scenarios